# Cycling in Ipopt

Tags: ampl, interior-point-method, ipopt

I am running a QCQP model in the following setup

- AMPL;
- MUMPS 5.6.2; And
- Ipopt 3.14.14, with the following parameters (cf. https://coin-or.github.io/Ipopt/OPTIONS.html):

  - check_derivatives_for_naninf=yes;
  - hessian_approximation=limited-memory;
  - hessian_approximation_space=nonlinear-variables;
  - inf_pr_output=internal;
  - line_search_method=cg-penalty;
  - max_iter=10000000;
  - mu_strategy=adaptive.

With the following Ipopt header.

```
Number of nonzeros in equality constraint Jacobian...:     3072
Number of nonzeros in inequality constraint Jacobian.:        0
Number of nonzeros in Lagrangian Hessian.............:        0
Total number of variables............................:     1024
                     variables with only lower bounds:        0
                variables with lower and upper bounds:     1024
                     variables with only upper bounds:        0
Total number of equality constraints.................:       65
Total number of inequality constraints...............:        0
        inequality constraints with only lower bounds:        0
   inequality constraints with lower and upper bounds:        0
        inequality constraints with only upper bounds:        0
```

And the following iteration log.

```
iter    objective    inf_pr   inf_du lg(mu)  ||d||  lg(rg) alpha_du alpha_pr  ls
33480  3.1818420e-01 9.96e-01 3.36e-02  -1.2 3.24e-07    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00c  1
33481  3.1812523e-01 9.96e-01 3.12e-02  -1.2 3.00e-07    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00c  1
33482  3.1799341e-01 9.96e-01 5.23e+04  -1.2 1.21e-06    -  1.00e+00 4.96e-01c  2
33483  3.1818420e-01 9.96e-01 3.36e-02  -1.2 3.24e-07    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00c  1
33484  3.1812523e-01 9.96e-01 3.12e-02  -1.2 3.00e-07    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00c  1
33485  3.1799341e-01 9.96e-01 5.23e+04  -1.2 1.21e-06    -  1.00e+00 4.96e-01c  2
33486  3.1818420e-01 9.96e-01 3.36e-02  -1.2 3.24e-07    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00c  1
33487  3.1812523e-01 9.96e-01 3.12e-02  -1.2 3.00e-07    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00c  1
33488  3.1799341e-01 9.96e-01 5.23e+04  -1.2 1.21e-06    -  1.00e+00 4.96e-01c  2
33489  3.1818420e-01 9.96e-01 3.36e-02  -1.2 3.24e-07    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00c  1
iter    objective    inf_pr   inf_du lg(mu)  ||d||  lg(rg) alpha_du alpha_pr  ls
33490  3.1812523e-01 9.96e-01 3.12e-02  -1.2 3.00e-07    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00c  1
33491  3.1799341e-01 9.96e-01 5.23e+04  -1.2 1.21e-06    -  1.00e+00 4.96e-01c  2
33492  3.1818420e-01 9.96e-01 3.36e-02  -1.2 3.24e-07    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00c  1
33493  3.1812523e-01 9.96e-01 3.12e-02  -1.2 3.00e-07    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00c  1
33494  3.1799341e-01 9.96e-01 5.23e+04  -1.2 1.21e-06    -  1.00e+00 4.96e-01c  2
33495  3.1818420e-01 9.96e-01 3.36e-02  -1.2 3.24e-07    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00c  1
33496  3.1812523e-01 9.96e-01 3.12e-02  -1.2 3.00e-07    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00c  1
33497  3.1799341e-01 9.96e-01 5.23e+04  -1.2 1.21e-06    -  1.00e+00 4.96e-01c  2
33498  3.1818420e-01 9.96e-01 3.36e-02  -1.2 3.24e-07    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00c  1
33499  3.1812523e-01 9.96e-01 3.12e-02  -1.2 3.00e-07    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00c  1
iter    objective    inf_pr   inf_du lg(mu)  ||d||  lg(rg) alpha_du alpha_pr  ls
33500  3.1799341e-01 9.96e-01 5.23e+04  -1.2 1.21e-06    -  1.00e+00 4.96e-01c  2
33501  3.1818420e-01 9.96e-01 3.36e-02  -1.2 3.24e-07    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00c  1
33502  3.1812523e-01 9.96e-01 3.12e-02  -1.2 3.00e-07    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00c  1
33503  3.1799341e-01 9.96e-01 5.23e+04  -1.2 1.21e-06    -  1.00e+00 4.96e-01c  2
33504  3.1818420e-01 9.96e-01 3.36e-02  -1.2 3.24e-07    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00c  1
33505  3.1812523e-01 9.96e-01 3.12e-02  -1.2 3.00e-07    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00c  1
33506  3.1799341e-01 9.96e-01 5.23e+04  -1.2 1.21e-06    -  1.00e+00 4.96e-01c  2
33507  3.1818420e-01 9.96e-01 3.36e-02  -1.2 3.24e-07    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00c  1
33508  3.1812523e-01 9.96e-01 3.12e-02  -1.2 3.00e-07    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00c  1
33509  3.1799341e-01 9.96e-01 5.23e+04  -1.2 1.21e-06    -  1.00e+00 4.96e-01c  2
iter    objective    inf_pr   inf_du lg(mu)  ||d||  lg(rg) alpha_du alpha_pr  ls
(REPEATS) 33510  3.1818420e-01 9.96e-01 3.36e-02  -1.2 3.24e-07    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00c  1
(REPEATS) 33511  3.1812523e-01 9.96e-01 3.12e-02  -1.2 3.00e-07    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00c  1
(REPEATS) 33512  3.1799341e-01 9.96e-01 5.23e+04  -1.2 1.21e-06    -  1.00e+00 4.96e-01c  2
(REPEATS) 33513  3.1818420e-01 9.96e-01 3.36e-02  -1.2 3.24e-07    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00c  1
(REPEATS) 33514  3.1812523e-01 9.96e-01 3.12e-02  -1.2 3.00e-07    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00c  1
(REPEATS) 33515  3.1799341e-01 9.96e-01 5.23e+04  -1.2 1.21e-06    -  1.00e+00 4.96e-01c  2
(REPEATS) 33516  3.1818420e-01 9.96e-01 3.36e-02  -1.2 3.24e-07    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00c  1
(REPEATS) 33517  3.1812523e-01 9.96e-01 3.12e-02  -1.2 3.00e-07    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00c  1
(REPEATS) 33518  3.1799341e-01 9.96e-01 5.23e+04  -1.2 1.21e-06    -  1.00e+00 4.96e-01c  2
(REPEATS) 33519  3.1818420e-01 9.96e-01 3.36e-02  -1.2 3.24e-07    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00c  1
iter    objective    inf_pr   inf_du lg(mu)  ||d||  lg(rg) alpha_du alpha_pr  ls
(REPEATS) 33520  3.1812523e-01 9.96e-01 3.12e-02  -1.2 3.00e-07    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00c  1
(REPEATS) 33521  3.1799341e-01 9.96e-01 5.23e+04  -1.2 1.21e-06    -  1.00e+00 4.96e-01c  2
(REPEATS) 33522  3.1818420e-01 9.96e-01 3.36e-02  -1.2 3.24e-07    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00c  1
(REPEATS) 33523  3.1812523e-01 9.96e-01 3.12e-02  -1.2 3.00e-07    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00c  1
(REPEATS) 33524  3.1799341e-01 9.96e-01 5.23e+04  -1.2 1.21e-06    -  1.00e+00 4.96e-01c  2
(REPEATS) 33525  3.1818420e-01 9.96e-01 3.36e-02  -1.2 3.24e-07    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00c  1
(REPEATS) 33526  3.1812523e-01 9.96e-01 3.12e-02  -1.2 3.00e-07    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00c  1
(REPEATS) 33527  3.1799341e-01 9.96e-01 5.23e+04  -1.2 1.21e-06    -  1.00e+00 4.96e-01c  2
(REPEATS) 33528  3.1818420e-01 9.96e-01 3.36e-02  -1.2 3.24e-07    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00c  1
(REPEATS) 33529  3.1812523e-01 9.96e-01 3.12e-02  -1.2 3.00e-07    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00c  1
iter    objective    inf_pr   inf_du lg(mu)  ||d||  lg(rg) alpha_du alpha_pr  ls
(REPEATS) 33530  3.1799341e-01 9.96e-01 5.23e+04  -1.2 1.21e-06    -  1.00e+00 4.96e-01c  2
(REPEATS) 33531  3.1818420e-01 9.96e-01 3.36e-02  -1.2 3.24e-07    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00c  1
(REPEATS) 33532  3.1812523e-01 9.96e-01 3.12e-02  -1.2 3.00e-07    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00c  1
(REPEATS) 33533  3.1799341e-01 9.96e-01 5.23e+04  -1.2 1.21e-06    -  1.00e+00 4.96e-01c  2
(REPEATS) 33534  3.1818420e-01 9.96e-01 3.36e-02  -1.2 3.24e-07    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00c  1
(REPEATS) 33535  3.1812523e-01 9.96e-01 3.12e-02  -1.2 3.00e-07    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00c  1
(REPEATS) 33536  3.1799341e-01 9.96e-01 5.23e+04  -1.2 1.21e-06    -  1.00e+00 4.96e-01c  2
(REPEATS) 33537  3.1818420e-01 9.96e-01 3.36e-02  -1.2 3.24e-07    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00c  1
(REPEATS) 33538  3.1812523e-01 9.96e-01 3.12e-02  -1.2 3.00e-07    -  1.00e+00 1.00e+00c  1
(REPEATS) 33539  3.1799341e-01 9.96e-01 5.23e+04  -1.2 1.21e-06    -  1.00e+00 4.96e-01c  2
```

Note that, the first 30 log entries keep repeating. In my execution, this behavior keeps up for hours. Unfortunately, I am too naive in the realms of Interior Point Methods (IPM), thus I am not that keen in what regards conjecturing the possible reason for this. I would like to know if someone has any suggestion of what may be the reason.

By the way, the inputted problem is feasible.

Comment: Try line_search_method=filter and see if that works better. It shouldn't be cycling.

Comment: Thanks, I will take the time to replicate the experiments, and then I get back here. Regards.

Comment: @CharlieVanaret, thank you very much, it worked for some cases, but still failing for other, I suppose this is the hyperparameter tuning trade-off.

Comment: Does it cycle on the unsolved instances, or does it reach the max iteration number?

Comment: It keeps cycling. Since the max_it is to large 10000000.

Comment: I'm afraid we might have to play with more advanced parameters here... Can you try setting gamma_phi to 1e-5 and gamma_theta to 1e-3?

Comment: Thanks for the support, I will check this out.

Comment: Hello, sorry for the late response. Ok, so, setting the 

- line_search_method=filter;
- With and without gamma_phi=1e-5 and gamma_theta=1e-3;

led to "infeasible solutions", by "infeasible" I mean, the linear equality constraints (Ax = b) were disrespected, for a more concise substantiation, I am dealing with an equality QCQP problem, i.e. all constraints are equalities. I will take the time to analize/calibrate the recommended parameters. 

Thanks and Regards.

Comment: OK thanks for the feedback. Are you sure your model is feasible?

Comment: Yes, it is, for instance, I am able to obtain feasible solutions by using the ALM Algencan, and the Gurobi MIQCQP solver. I was trying to see how IPMs would behave with such problems.

Comment: Got it. I would also set mu_strategy to its default parameter (monotone).

Comment: Thank you so much, this solved the cycling issue. But, still having problems in finding solutions, for instance, I am running now a problem with ~1000 variables, and in the iteration 150000 no solution found whatsoever. Thanks for the support.

Comment: Can you post the last few lines of the log?

Comment: @CharlieVanaret thank you so much for all the support. After some days of investigation, I found the reason. Basically, I am dealing with a Ball Constrained Optimization Problem (BCOP), characterized by constraints of type $\| x \|_2^2 = k$. And, for this type of problem; according to the paper "A Filter Active-Set Algorithm for Ball/Sphere Constrained Optimization Problem" (10.1137/140989078) at paragraphs 3, 4 and 5; relying on traditional SQP methods ("On the implementation of an interior-point filter line-search algorithm" section 2.2 (10.1007/s10107-004-0559-y)) may lead to bad results.

Comment: Furthermore, the BCOP paper (10.1137/140989078) makes a point on the use of L-BFGS for this type of problem. What explains why ipopt with L-BFGS worked for some instances. Also, as mentioned in paragraph 4 of section 1, one of the reasons for the struggling when solving this type of problem may be the number of variables I am taking into the $l$-2 norm, for example, the above experiments work just fine for small instances, but when a certain threshold on the number of variables is reached, the behavious we've been commenting so far manifests.

Comment: Btw, along with the BCOP constraints $\| x \|_2^2 = k$, and also using the bounds $-1 \leqslant x \leqslant 1$, where $x \in \mathbb{R}^k$. That is, we have a hypercube embedded within the hypersphere (Ball).